# Source webpage using Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome

I want to use python to scrape the table from website below but it looks like it includes a JavaScript. How can I use Chrome developer tools to locate the website that populates the table?

Website is

https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/natural-gas/natural-gas_quotes_settlements_futures.html

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

They are bringing the table values using this XHR request. (https://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/Settlements/Futures/Settlements/444/FUT?tradeDate=08/20/2018&strategy=DEFAULT&pageSize=50&_=1534831963390)

So just load this link and get all tables values.

Happy scraping :)